# ReactJs. A component isn't hide onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I clicking on a button, a component showing. If again clicking on the button the component isn't changing a state.

```
    state = {
        isActive: true
    } 
    toggleMnu = () => {
        this.setState({isActive: false});
    }; // Show menu function

    hideMnu = () => {
        this.setState({isActive: true});
    }; // Hide menu function

    toggleOnClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        !this.props.hideMnu
            ? this.toggleMnu()
            : this.hideMnu();
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleOnClick}>Menu</button>
            {this.state.isActive ? null : <div className="extended-menu-item">
            {menuInfo.map((menuItem ,index)=>{return <ExtendedMenuItem click= {this.hideExtendedNav} {...menuItem} key={index}/>
        })} // The component which shows menu on click   
    )}
```

Comment: Your toggle function is checking `hideMnu` prop, instead of `isActive` state.

Comment: Thx, I changed !this.props.hideMnu to this.state.isActive is working!

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're changing the state directly. You should do like this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {isActive: !prevState.isActive}
  // reverse old state ^^
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 state = {
    isActive: true
} 
toggleMnu = () => {
    this.setState({isActive: !this.state.isActive});
}; 

render(){
    return(
        <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleMnu}>Menu</button>
        {this.state.isActive ? null : <div className="extended-menu-item">
        {menuInfo.map((menuItem ,index)=>{return <ExtendedMenuItem click= {this.hideExtendedNav} {...menuItem} key={index}/>
    })} // The component which shows menu on click   
)}
```

I don't know what you are doing with props there, but if the purpose is to change the state try using this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
state = {
    isActive: true
} 

toggleMnu = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
       isActive: !prevState.isActive
    }));
}; // Show menu function


render(){
    return(
        <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleMnu}>Menu</button>
        {this.state.isActive ? null : <div className="extended-menu-item">
        {menuInfo.map((menuItem ,index)=>{return <ExtendedMenuItem click= {this.hideExtendedNav} {...menuItem} key={index}/>
    })} // The component which shows menu on click   
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example for your code. please change code according your scenario.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isActive: true
    }
    this.toggleOnClick = this.toggleOnClick.bind(this);
  }
  
  toggleMnu = () => {
        this.setState({isActive: false});
    }; // Show menu function

    hideMnu = () => {
        this.setState({isActive: true});
    }; // Hide menu function

    toggleOnClick = () => {
        this.setState({isActive: !this.state.isActive});
        console.log('this.state.isActive: ', this.state.isActive);
    };

  render() {  
    //let filed = this.state.isActive ? <h2>AAA</h2> : null;  
  
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleOnClick}>Menu</button>
        {this.state.isActive ? <h2>AAA</h2> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```